# electric current

Tags: electricity, electric-current

How can positive charges flow in current?
I mean , we know that there is a particle called electron which can move but there is no such positively charged particle which can flow , there can be positively charged atoms but atoms do not flow !!

Comment: the electrons actually flow in the opposite way which is equivalent to a positive charge flow in the other direction

Comment: Positively charged ions flowing in a liquid or even solid solution is also an electric current.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called a *hole*, check it out [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_hole). This is a somewhat controversial "particle" if you will, because it can be argued to exist as much as it can be argued to not exist. In essence, when an electron escapes its atom, one can say that a positively charged "hole" replaces it (this conserves charge). So when electrons move, holes appear to move in the opposite direction, producing current. Generally though, ANY kind of moving charge is a current, *i.e.* a group of $Na^+$ moving through a medium would constitute a positive current.

**Edit:** be aware that in a metal (*i.e.* wire) this works a little differently because the metal has "free" electrons, check out this nice [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6513/why-are-there-free-electrons-in-a-metal) on Chem SE about why they are free.

**Bonus Round:** Although one can say that holes don't really exist, in electrical engineering they surely do. [Complimentary Metal-Oxide Semiconductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS) (CMOS) technology is based on carrying electrons and holes separately, and strategically. Two kinds of transistors, PMOSFET and NMOSFET (FET = Field effect transistor) are used to carry holes and electrons respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Although metal wires conduct electricity using mobile (negative) electrons there are many other conductor which conduct electricity using both negative and positive charge carriers.

For example the conduction process in liquids is with mobile positive and negative ions and liquids which do not have such ions (many organic molecules) do not conduct electricity.
In the electrolysis of copper sulphate there are positive copper and hydrogen ions and negative sulphate and hydroxyl ions moving around.
Once a gas is ionised as for example when there is a spark it is electrons, and both positive and negative ions responsible for the conduction process.

In semiconductor Physics the conduction process is often discuss in terms of negative electrons and positive holes.
Here you have to be careful because in fact it is only electrons which conduct the electricity but the charge carriers called holes are electrons which move in the same direction as the electric field.
This is a quantum mechanical effect with a quantity called effective mass being important.
To describe the behaviour of such electrons one could have either have said that the electrons were like negative charge carriers with a negative effective mass or like positive charge carriers with a positive effective mass.
The latter description was chosen and the charge carrier was called a hole.